# Search google+ api for public posts and pages

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to use the google-api-php-client SDK along with google plus api service. The documentation isnt very clear. Do I search activities? Do I need to get an oAuth token to do what i want?

**Update:** Now using

```
    $params = array(
              'orderBy' => 'best',
              'maxResults' => '20',
              'query' => 'Google+ API'
            );

   $results = $plus->activities->search($params);
```

returns

```
    Array
(
    [kind] => plus#activityFeed
    [etag] => "5NTCbsXue5u92XtxuV0QeM_x9B4/58mHUy-IErItGIABIAhYhhUjJ-M"
    [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query&maxResults=10
    [title] => Plus Search
    [updated] => 2012-09-27T14:03:35.132Z
    [id] => tag:google.com,2010:es-search-feed:z80ghJXVZe9m59_5-Ydk2g
    [items] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an OAuth token to search activities. You only need to register a Developer Key in the Google APIs Console.

1. Register a Developer Key in the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=plus).
2. Check out the latest version of the [Google APIs PHP Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/checkout) .
3. Take a look at the Google+ sample app. https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/plus/index.php

Sample:

```
$params = array(
  'orderBy' => 'best',
  'maxResults' => '20',
  'query' => 'Google+ API'
);

$results = $plus->activities->search($params);
foreach($results['items'] as $result) {
  print "Result: {$result['object']['content']}\n";
}
```

Comment: I dont get any results returned. Updated question with whats returned. Also get a warning: rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given googleplus/google-api-php-client/src/io/apiREST.php, line 129]

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem and here is how I have done it:

```
$query = "some query";    
$params = array(
      'orderBy' => 'best',
      'maxResults' => '20',
);

$results = $plus->activities->search($query, $params);
foreach($results['items'] as $result) {
      print "Result: {$result['object']['content']}\n";
}
```

Even dough in an examples query is a part of parameters it is not. It should be sent as separated value as you can see in the implementation of the search method for plus service [Link](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Plus.php#L408)

Hope this helps you.